# How to get real JPanel Size?

Tags: java, swing, size, jpanel

How should I get real JPanel size in JFrame?

Comment: "By really calling [`getSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getSize%28%29)."  It is possible that the method is being called prior to when it becomes realized. For more specific advice,  post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: As @Andrew says. But you can't do it until its been rendered.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The size will be `0,0` until it is displayed because the components and layout are not calculated beforehand.

Comment: Is there any call back for initialising child components of jPanel after it got its real width and height?

Comment: Is there a way to force the layout to calculate component locations and sizes without calling `setVisible(true)`?

Comment: @SakkeerHussain if you queue a runnable with [`SwingUtilities#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) *after* calling `setVisible(true)` on your JFrame, then that runnable will be executed after the panel is assigned its size. With this method, however, you will have to initialize your panel beforehand and update it after it's actually visible.

Answer (score 9):

`thePanel.getSize();`

This returns the Dimension.

I sometimes add a ComponentListener to show the dimension when the panel is resized.

EDIT: If you want the size of the content pane of the JFrame then

```
theFrame.getContentPane().getSize();
```

Comment: It does not give real size java.awt.Dimension[width=0,height=0]  I used that before

Comment: @RobertKilar km half answered you question, add a ComponentLsterner to the panel you're interested in & monitor the componentResized event

Comment: @RobertKilar you're probably getting the size before its rendered. Try the component listener's resize event handler.